# How can I get a mailto link in an org-mode latex export to PDF for the #+email: keyword

Tags: org-export, latex, email, pdf

When I'm specifying my mail address

```
#+email: bla@comp.org
```

I'm getting a **text** footnote bla@comp.org for an org latex export of a report.  I'd like to have a complete mailto hyperlink though.

I tried

```
#+email: [[mailto:bla@comp.org][bla@comp.org]]
```

or

```
#+email: \href{mailto:bla@comp.org}{bla@comp.org}
```

(The problem here seems to be that org-mode escapes the backslashes and braces for the latex export.  So the latex interpreter sees only $\backslash$href instead of the \href command.)

and

```
#+email: mailto:bla@comp.org
```

but after exporting the org file to pdf-latex I'm just getting the complete line after #+email as text in the footnote.

Example of a failed attempt:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems kind of grungy but it works:

```
#+latex_class: report
#+options: author:nil  email:nil
#+latex_header: \author{Some user \thanks{\href{mailto:bla@comp.org}{bla@comp.org}}}
```

Rest of your stuff here.

Comment: Hi John, thank you very much indeed.  I like it: 1) stop ox-latex from interfering 2) feed pure latex, all in all not too dirty... ;-)